# In R and INLA, how do I graph results of 'rw2' model?

Tags: r, inla

I'm working with model 2 of INLA's [Zambia example](http://www.r-inla.org/examples/case-studies/martino-and-rue-2010/code-for-the-zambia-example) in R:

```
formula.mod2 = hazstd ~ f(agc, model = "rw2") +
  f(district, model="besag", graph = g, param = c(1,0.01)) +
  f(distr.unstruct, model="iid", param = c(1,0.01)) +
  edu1 + edu2 + tpr + sex + bmi

mod2  =  inla(formula.mod2, data = Zambia, control.family = list(initial = 1),
  control.inla = list(h = 1e-4),
  control.compute = list(dic = TRUE,cpo=TRUE),
  verbose = TRUE)
```

Everything works as advertised. In the [Martino and Rue (2010)](http://www.r-inla.org/examples/case-studies/martino-and-rue-2010) materials (section 5.2) I noticed nice graph of the 'Fig. 2a Estimated effect of age (posterior mean together with 2.5% and 97.5% quantiles) using MOD2'.

[image]

PS I asked that question on [INLA user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/r-inla-discussion-group/RzDAWlhOdxo); cross posting here to get more attention.

My question is where do I find the data and how do I plot a graph like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Håvard Rue kindly provided an [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/r-inla-discussion-group/RzDAWlhOdxo/oMSVBy_N5Q4J) on INLA group. The variables needed for a plot are in `mod2$summary.random$agc` and the plot can be constructed by:

```
names(mod2$summary.random$agc)
summary(mod2$summary.random$agc$"0.5quant")

library("ggplot2")

mydata <- as.data.frame(mod2$summary.random$agc)

ggplot(mydata) +   
  geom_line(aes(ID, `0.5quant`)) +   
  geom_line(aes(ID, `0.025quant`), linetype="dashed") +   
  geom_line(aes(ID, `0.975quant`), linetype="dashed")
```